# How to Integrate Flurry Analytics into iOS App using swift?

Tags: swift, flurry-analytics

Here I Have Post my code what i am tried for integrate Flurry Analytics into my app but I made a mistake so please help me for clear that?

```
    Flurry.startSession("4YRB33WV8M2B33TY353J");
    Flurry.logEvent("PreeSample");
    Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)  // records app crashing in Flurry
    Flurry.setDebugLogEnabled(true)
    Flurry.setLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. The people here help, whereever possible but we need more informations. What is the error? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @sarvana kumar Where do you try to log? In the applicationDidFinishWithOptions method?

Comment: First of all I need what is the use of Flurry Analytics?

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        
        
        Flurry.startSession("4YRB33WV8M2B33TY353J");
        Flurry.logEvent("PreeSample");
        Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)  // records app crashing in Flurry
        Flurry.setDebugLogEnabled(true)
        Flurry.setLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)

Comment: I tried in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: I confused about output, What is the output for flurry analytics and how it shows?

Comment: Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f93d9c75f90> { URL: https://data.flurry.com/aas.do } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 122;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 08:59:17 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
} }]

Comment: Output Displayed like this following .....   Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f93d9c75f90> { URL: https://data.flurry.com/aas.do } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 122;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 08:59:17 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
} }]

Comment: Are you using the application-specific key? If not check the manage-menu at the application-dashboard.

Comment: Yes..I used the key..